# VB + ASP.net : How to disable requiredfieldvalidator on condition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to disable a required field validator for a dropdown list based on the selected value of a separate dropdown list.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control " ID="ddl_Title" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false">
                                        <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Mr</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Mrs</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Ms</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Miss</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                                   </asp:DropDownList>
                              </div>


                             <div class="row" id="Other">
                             <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                             <div class="col-md-2"><asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control " ID="ddl_Other" Width="155"></asp:DropDownList>
                             <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4"
                                                         runat="server"
                                                         ControlToValidate="ddl_Other"
                                                         ErrorMessage="*Title is required."
                                                         Forecolor="Red" 
                                                         Display="Dynamic"
                                                         InitialValue="-1">
                             </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                             <div class="col-md-9"></div>                                                                         
                            </div>
                         </div>
```

So the validation control is only enabled when the selected value of the first dropdown list is "Other"

```
    If ddl_Title.SelectedValue Is "Other" Then

        RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = True

    Else

        RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = False

    End If
```

How do I make this work??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to the DropDownList with `AutoPostBack` set to `true`.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control " ID="ddl_Title" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_Title_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

And then in code behind.

```
Protected Sub ddl_Title_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If ddl_Title.SelectedValue Is "Other" Then
        RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = True
    Else
        RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make **CauseValidation** property of your dropdown true.

From msdn.

> true if the control causes validation to be performed on any controls
>   requiring validation when it receives focus; otherwise, false. The
>   default is true.